# Is Wikipedia's example of a function not in a tensor product correct?

Tags: analysis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space#Motivations_from_geometry explains that we need to take the completed tensor product for $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to hold. I agree with this, but the example they give of a function not in the uncompleted tensor product is $\sin(x+y).$ Isn't
$\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\otimes\cos(y) + \cos(x)\otimes\sin(y),$
though?

Comment: You're right and the Wikipedia article is incorrect. It says $\sin (x + y)$ isn't a pure tensor but as you say it is a sum of two pure tensors. A correct example of a function not in the tensor product is $e^{xy}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks!